# SQL Pulling results by year

Tags: sql, oracle, date

**Problem:**  I have dated salary information stored in a table.  I need to display one result per year.  For each year, I want to display the max dated record from the year prior. The problem is that some years don’t have data  (salary didn’t change).  I need these rows to contain the max record prior to that year (it may be from 2 years before or even 3).

My query right now would work if each row has data…  but it doesn’t account for years where there is no data.  How can I update this sql to pull the desired results below:

**Example of data:**

sch_sal_svc.beg_date    -------sch_sal_svc.beg_date.per_plan_data

- 1/1/2007---100
- 6/1/2007---200
- 1/1/2008---300
- 1/1/2011---400
- 8/1/2011---500
- 9/1/2012---600

Current Results

- 1/1/2008---200
- 1/1/2011---300
- 1/1/2012---500

Desired Results

- 1/1/2008---200
- 1/1/2009---300
- 1/1/2010---300
- 1/1/2011---300
- 1/1/2012---500

**SQL:**

```
SELECT
years.control_id,
years.ssn,
ebe.plan_id,
to_number(to_char(years.sal_date,'yyyy')),
null as per_plan_salary,
    null as per_vest_hours,
    null as per_credsvc_hours,
    LEAST(s.rate_1,cl.comp_genl),
    null as salary_1,
    null as per_comm,
    null as per_overtime,
    null as per_ncr,
    null as salary_2
FROM
    sch_sal_svc s
    , (select distinct ssn, control_id, TRUNC(beg_date,'YEAR') as sal_date from sch_sal_svc where beg_date > to_date('12/31/1900', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) years
    , employee_benefit_elig ebe, compliance_limits cl
WHERE
    years.ssn = ebe.ssn
    and years.control_id = ebe.control_id
    and to_number(to_char(years.sal_date,'yyyy')) = cl.limit_year
    and to_number(to_char(years.sal_date,'yyyy')) <= to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'))
    and s.beg_date = (
        select max(s2.beg_date) from sch_sal_svc s2
        where s2.ssn = years.ssn and s2.control_id = years.control_id
        and s2.beg_date <= years.sal_date
    )
    and s.ssn = years.ssn
    and s.control_id = years.control_id
    and ebe.benefit_id = 'DB'
    and ebe.control_id = 'CLIENT'
    and ebe.plan_id in ('100', '200')
```

Comment: Here is a good tip for writing SQL questions on Stackoverflow, use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create a "Example database" and post a link in the question, this will let you and people posting answers "check their work" to see the output of the query is what you where looking for. Also to get nice looking tables for example result sets use [this website](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) (created by SO user [Sensful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/143909/senseful)) and wrap the table in `<pre></pre>` html tags

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE sch_sal_svc
(
    beg_date      DATE
,   per_plan_data NUMBER
);


INSERT INTO sch_sal_svc VALUES(TO_DATE('01/01/2007', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 100);
INSERT INTO sch_sal_svc VALUES(TO_DATE('06/01/2007', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 200);
INSERT INTO sch_sal_svc VALUES(TO_DATE('01/01/2008', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 300);
INSERT INTO sch_sal_svc VALUES(TO_DATE('01/01/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 400);
INSERT INTO sch_sal_svc VALUES(TO_DATE('08/01/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 500);
INSERT INTO sch_sal_svc VALUES(TO_DATE('09/01/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 600);


SELECT  MIN(beg_date) FROM sch_sal_svc;
-- 2007-01-01 00:00:00


SELECT  d.r_level + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'YEAR') AS d_date
,       NVL    -- the salary must be updated at least once in three years
        (
            NVL
            (
                NVL
                (
                    s.per_plan_data
                ,   LAG(s.per_plan_data, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY d.r_level)
                )
            ,   LAG(s.per_plan_data, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY d.r_level)
            )
        ,   LAG(s.per_plan_data, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY d.r_level)
        ) AS lag_per_plan_data
FROM
(
        SELECT  DATE'2006-01-01' + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(LEVEL, 'YEAR') AS r_level    -- min beg_date minus 1
        FROM    DUAL
        CONNECT BY
                LEVEL < (SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(beg_date), 'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(MIN(beg_date), 'YYYY') + 2 FROM sch_sal_svc)
)  d
LEFT    JOIN
(
        SELECT  beg_date
        ,       per_plan_data
        FROM    sch_sal_svc
        WHERE   (beg_date) IN
                (
                    SELECT  MAX(beg_date)
                    FROM    sch_sal_svc
                    GROUP   BY
                            TRUNC(beg_date, 'YYYY')
                )
)  s
ON      d.r_level = TRUNC(s.beg_date, 'YYYY')
;

/*
2008-01-01 00:00:00 200
2009-01-01 00:00:00 300
2010-01-01 00:00:00 300
2011-01-01 00:00:00 300
2012-01-01 00:00:00 500
2013-01-01 00:00:00 600
*/
```